# Google Policy Controller issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to setup the policy controller, but facing issue. It says "deployment in error state: Progress deadline exceeded"

When i troubleshooted, it says account is missing

I tried to create one but it gives error.

> ubuntu# gcloud iam service-accounts create
> service-123456@serverless-robot-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com
>
> --description="Policy Controller"
>
> --display-name="service-123456@serverless-robot-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com"

```
The account ID "service-123456@serverless-robot-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com" does not have a length between 6 and 30.
```

Can someone please help on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The error message you are encountering indicates that the account ID you provided does not meet the required length criteria. Service account IDs must be between 6 and 30 characters long. In your case, the account ID you provided is more than 30.

You need to provide a valid service account ID that adheres to the length requirements.

Here's an example:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts create my-service-account \
--description="Policy Controller" \
--display-name="My Service Account"
```